# Finding Cov($x,\frac1x$)

Tags: probability

Given a random variable $X$ with probability density function $$f(x)=\frac5{x^6}\mathbf 1_{\{x>1\}}$$

I am trying to find the cov($x,\frac1x$).

Opening the covariance I get that $\Rightarrow E1-E(x)*E(\frac1x)$

From calculations I get that $E(x)=1$.

After making the transformation For $\frac1x$ I find that $f(\frac1x)=5x^4$. and that $E(\frac1x)$ is $\frac56$.

Giving me a final answer of $\frac16$, unfortunately the answer is supposed to be $\frac{-1}{24}$

Any Ideas what I'm going wrong?

Comment: "From calculations I get that E(x)=1" How?

Comment: Right!! it is 5/4. Silly mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of $E(X)$ is not correct.

$E(X)=\int_\mathbb{R} xf(x)dx=\int_1^\infty \frac{5}{x^5}dx=-\frac{5}{4}x^{-4}\rvert_1^\infty=\frac{5}{4}$

Similarly you can calculate $E(\frac{1}{X})=\frac{5}{6}$. Using this and definition of covariance, you will get the correct answer.